# Onepage with shortcodes

Tags: theme-development, shortcode

i build a onepage wordpress theme , and for showing all my pages in one page i use a loop  , but shortcodes don't work (Ex : contact form 7 : the form is showing but don't work at all) this is my code :

```
            <?php
            /*
              Template Name: Pulse one page
             */
            $this_page = $post->ID;
            get_header();
            ?>

            <div class="hs-content-scroller">
                <!-- Header -->
                <div id="header_container">
                    <div id="header">
                        <div><a class="home"><i class="fa fa-home"></i></a>
                        </div>
                        <div><a href="" class="previous-page arrow"><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i></a>
                        </div>
                        <div><a href="" class="next-page arrow"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a>
                        </div>
                        <!-- News scroll -->
                        <?php
                        $news_items = ot_get_option('header_news', array());
                        if (!empty($news_items)) {
                            ?>
                            <div class="news-scroll">
                                <span><i class="fa fa-line-chart"></i>RECENT ACTIVITY : </span>
                                <ul id="marquee" class="marquee">
                                    <?php
                                    foreach ($news_items as $news_item) {

                                        echo '<li><strong>' . $news_item['title'] . '</strong>' . $news_item['header_news_content'] . '</li>';
                                    }
                                    ?>


                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        <?php } ?>
                        <!-- End News scroll -->
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- End Header -->
                <!-- hs-content-wrapper -->
                <div class="hs-content-wrapper">
                    <?php
                    $args = array('order' => 'ASC',
                        'orderby' => 'menu_order',
                        'post_type' => 'page',
                        'post__not_in' => array($this_page),
                        'posts_per_page' => -1,
                    );
                    $the_query = new WP_Query($args);

            // The Loop
                    if ($the_query->have_posts()) :

                        while ($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post();
                            $the_sub_query = new WP_Query(array('page_id' => $the_query->post->ID));
                            if ($the_sub_query->is_posts_page) {
                                continue;
                            }
                            $mytemplate = get_post_meta($the_query->post->ID, '_wp_page_template', true);
                            $title = $the_query->post->post_title;
                            echo "<article class='hs-content' id='section" . $the_query->post->menu_order . "'>";
                            echo "<span class='sec-icon fa " . get_post_meta($the_query->post->ID, 'iconfont-select', true) . "'></span>";
                            echo "<div class='hs-inner'>";
                            echo "<span class='before-title'>.0" . $the_query->post->menu_order . "</span>";
                            echo "<h2>$title</h2>";
                            if ($mytemplate != null) {
                                the_content();
                                get_template_part(substr($mytemplate, 0, -4));
                            } else {
                                the_content();
                            }
                            echo "</div>";
                            echo "</article>";

                        endwhile;
                    endif;

            // Reset Post Data
                    wp_reset_postdata();
                    ?>
                </div>
                <!-- End hs-content-wrapper -->
            </div>
            <!-- End hs-content-scroller -->
            <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: does your template call `wp_head` and `wp_footer` to output the necessary styles and scripts?

Comment: Yes , all works fine except shortcodes

Comment: @geeky87 i have put your code into index.php of Twenty_Fifteen theme, it working fine there, so you have problem with your theme

Comment: @HiteshSiddhapura : haev you testing the contact form 7 shortcode ?

Comment: yes i have test contact form 7 shortcode @geeky87

Comment: @HiteshSiddhapura i just testing it in post page and it's work fine but not in onepage , that's weird . thanks for your feedback

Comment: @geeky87 show your complete code for one page

Comment: @HiteshSiddhapura I just added my full one page code

Comment: @geeky87 its working fine into Twenty Fifteen theme, it confirm any issue with your functions.php or other theme file

Answer (score -1):

Replace all your `the_content();` with `echo do_shortcode(get_the_content());`

Comment: Please explain your logic behind this